# Move a label to a new position relative to its original position in java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a label and I want to move it to a new position relative to its previous one. Below is what I have done but its not working.

```
Insets insets = slabel.getInsets();
slabel.setLocation(30 + insets.top, insets.top);
```

`slabel` is the label. Basically what I want is, say if original the label was at (20, 30) then move it to (50, 30).
How to do it?

Comment: have you tried passing  **constant  values** ?? 
`slabel.setLocation(50,30);` Any luck with this ??

Comment: But set absolute location is of no use for me. I want to reposition it relatively  over and over again

Comment: I am not saying to use it , just try with it if it is working then you can probably use this 
`label.setLocation((label.getLocationOnScreen().x+30), label.getLocationOnScreen().y);`

Comment: No above line didn't work. After this, the label becomes invisible. Is it possible that the label seems hidden because it after relocation it goes down another label. Coz, I have many labels one over another. If thats the case, is it possible to keep a label always on top of others?

Comment: You don't want to get the location of the component on the screen. You need the location of the component relative to its parent container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move a label relative to it last position you would use:

```
Point location = label.getLocation();
label.setLocation(location.x + 30, location.y);
```

> is it possible to keep a label always on top of others?

Yes, this it referred to as the components Z-Order. You can change the Z-Order of a component by using:

```
panel.setZOrder(label, 0);
```

First just try setting the location.